# Call method on KeyDown Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, keydown

I'm trying to fire a method on KeyDown Escape button. I did an event handler KeyDown on my XAML.

```
<Page
   x:Name="pageRoot"
   x:Class="CYBOracleProject.Chapter1_1"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:CYBOracleProject"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d" Tapped="NxtDialog" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"
   IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" KeyDown="RestartGame">
```

Code File .cs:

```
private void RestartGame(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Escape)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, however. The method does not fire up.

**Does anyone know how to solve this?**

Comment: What does your debugger tell you? Does the event handler get called?

Comment: @RowlandShaw it launches normally. Pressing escape does nothing at all.

Comment: so what is the value of `e.Key` when the event handler is called?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't think I've added that.. Can you help me deduce a solution?